# Sequence lenght analysis of the Solovay-Kitaev Algorithm

Tags: solovay-kitaev-algorithm

In the paper by Dawson and Nielsen where they develop [an algorithm for the Solovay-Kitaev Theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0505030), they analyze the lenght of the output noting how, for an approximation of degree $n$, the lenght of the output sequence is $5l_{(n-1)}$ where $l_{(n-1)}$ is the lenght of the sequence for the approximation of degree $n-1$.
They conclude that the algorithm produces a sequence asymptotically of lenght $O(5^n)$.
We can then work on the recurrence for the approximation error $\epsilon_n$, and by isolating $n$ we arrive at this formula: $$n = \left \lceil  {\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\ln(1/\epsilon \cdot c_{appr}^2)}{\ln(1/\epsilon_0 \cdot c_{appr}^2)}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}}\right \rceil $$
Then they affirm how substituting the right hand side of this formula into $O(5^n)$ allows us to rewrite it in terms of $\epsilon$ to get the result stated in the theorem of page 4 of the paper: $O\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)^{3.97}\right)$, but I don't get wich passages we need to perform to arrive at such conclusion. Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use the rule of conversion of logarithms:
$$ \log_b x = \frac{\log_c x}{\log_c b}.$$

For clarity define the following quantity:
$$
A:= \frac{\ln(1/\epsilon \cdot c_{appr}^2)}{\ln(1/\epsilon_0 \cdot c_{appr}^2)}.
$$
Now we can write
$$
n = \left \lceil  {\frac{\ln \left( \frac{\ln(1/\epsilon \cdot c_{appr}^2)}{\ln(1/\epsilon_0 \cdot c_{appr}^2)} \right)}{\ln(3/2)}}\right \rceil = \left \lceil  {\frac{\ln(A)}{\ln(3/2)}}\right \rceil.
$$

We use the log conversion rule to rewrite $\ln(A)$:
$$
\ln(A) = \frac{\log_5 A}{\log_5 e}.
$$
So we get
$$
n = \left \lceil  {\frac{\frac{\log_5 A}{\log_5 e}}{\ln(3/2)}}\right \rceil.
$$
Now, substitute the above equation into $O(5^n)$ and ignore the ceiling operation with the Big $O$:
$$
5^n = 5^{\frac{\frac{\log_5 A}{\log_5 e}}{\ln(3/2)}} = \left ( 5^{\log_5 A} \right)^{\frac{\frac{1}{\log_5 e}}{\ln(3/2)}} = (A)^{\frac{\frac{1}{\log_5 e}}{\ln(3/2)}}.
$$
Next, we use the log conversion again to rewrite $\log_5 e$ as follows:
$$
\log_5 e = \frac{\ln e}{\ln 5} = \frac{1}{\ln 5}.
$$
Hence, we can write
$$
5^n = (A)^{\frac{\ln 5}{\ln(3/2)}}.
$$
So, we have
$$
5^n = (A)^{\frac{\ln 5}{\ln(3/2)}} = \left( \frac{\ln(1/\epsilon \cdot c_{appr}^2)}{\ln(1/\epsilon_0 \cdot c_{appr}^2)} \right)^{\frac{\ln 5}{\ln(3/2)}}.
$$

Note that $\ln(1/\epsilon_0 \cdot c_{appr}^2)$ is constant in $\epsilon$, so it will disappear when we push it through Big $O$. Also, we can absorb the constant $c^2_{appr}$ into $\epsilon$. Therefore, we get the final result:
$$
l_{\epsilon} = O\left( \ln(1/\epsilon ) ^{\frac{\ln 5}{\ln(3/2)}} \right).
$$
We also have $\frac{\ln 5}{\ln(3/2)} \approx 3.97$. So we get the result in the theorem:
$$
l_{\epsilon} = O\left( \ln(1/\epsilon ) ^{3.97} \right).
$$

We can do the same thing for $O(3^n)$ to get :
$$
t_{\epsilon} = O\left( \ln(1/\epsilon ) ^{\frac{\ln 3}{\ln(3/2)}} \right).
$$
The above can also be written as presented in the theorem:
$$
t_{\epsilon}= O\left( \ln(1/\epsilon ) ^{2.71} \right).
$$